# Aframe next previous function

Tags: aframe

Is anyone aware of a next/previous component that works inside WebVR with Aframe, so that if I am looking at an entity with id entity1 at position 0 0 -3, then I click next and I am looking at an entity with id entity2 at position 0 0 -3 replacing the previous entity, the previous entity returns position y -3 and scale 0 0 0, I click next again and now I am looking at entity with id entity3 which is now at position 0 0 3

I have been exploring how to build a next button starting with either an array or a javascript switch so that each time I press click, (listening for clicks on the next button) it brings me another new entity, so I might click next 6 times and see 6 different entities at position 0 0 -3, with each new entity replacing the previous entity, similarly a back button would do the same process but in reverse order.

Here is the idea in code, I am trying to complete it, but I’m getting lost in the forest for the trees so to speak.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("carousel", {
   init: function() {
         this.el.addEventListener("turn_carousel_left", (e) => {
       document.querySelectorAll('.carousel_left').forEach(function(e){
        e.emit('close_the_menu');
       emit +1 carousel index
     this.el.addEventListener("turn_carousel_right", (e) => {
      listen right events
       emit -1 carousel index

       if carousel index = 1 then emit position_named_1
       selected_carsouel_item = carousel_index_list[carouselindex]
```

http://carousel-b.glitch.me

Comment: The question scope is large. Hard to provide a concise answer. I would recommend reducing it to just a carrousel of basic shapes. Leaving aside images and video for simplicity. Providing a simple working link will also help identify roadblocks and areas to give specific advice.

Comment: here is some code I'm working on, it sort of works but then it breaks, can you help me fix it? http://carousel-b.glitch.me – Micah Blumberg 6 mins ago   delete

Comment: solved thanks to someone in the aframe slack, feel free to check out the solution in the linked page

Comment: @MicahBlumberg Good Job